# How to optimize this CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, optimization, cuda

I've profiled my model and it seems that this kernel accounts for about 2/3 of my total runtime.  I was looking for suggestions to optimize it.  The code is as follows.

```
__global__ void calcFlux(double* concs, double* fluxes, double* dt)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    fluxes[idx]=knowles_flux(idx, concs);
    //fluxes[idx]=flux(idx, concs);
}

__device__ double knowles_flux(int r, double *conc)
{
    double frag_term = 0;
    double flux = 0;
    if (r == ((maxlength)-1))
    {
        //Calculation type : "Max"
        flux = -km*(r)*conc[r]+2*(ka)*conc[r-1]*conc[0];
    }
    else if (r > ((nc)-1))
    {
        //Calculation type : "F"
        //arrSum3(conc, &frag_term, r+1, maxlength-1);
        for (int s = r+1; s < (maxlength); s++)
        {
            frag_term += conc[s];
        }
        flux = -(km)*(r)*conc[r] + 2*(km)*frag_term - 2*(ka)*conc[r]*conc[0] + 2*(ka)*conc[r-1]*conc[0];
    }
    else if (r == ((nc)-1))
    {
        //Calculation type : "N"
        //arrSum3(conc, &frag_term, r+1, maxlength-1);
        for (int s = r+1; s < (maxlength); s++)
        {
            frag_term += conc[s];
        }
        flux = (kn)*pow(conc[0],(nc)) + 2*(km)*frag_term - 2*(ka)*conc[r]*conc[0];
    }
    else if (r < ((nc)-1))
    {
    //Calculation type : "O"
        flux = 0;
    }
    return flux;
}
```

Just to give you an idea of why the for loop is an issue, this kernel is launched on an array of about maxlength = 9000 elements.  For our purposes now, nc is in the range of 2-6. Here's an illustration of how this kernel processes the incoming array (conc).  For this array, five different types of calculations need to be applied to different groups of elements.

```
Array element : 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 8955 8956 8957 8958 8959 8960
Type of calc  : M O O O O O N F F F ...   F   F    F    F    F   Max
```

The potential problems I've been trying to deal with right now are branch divergence from the quadruple if-else and the for loop.

My idea for dealing with the branch divergence is to break this kernel down into four separate device functions or kernels that treat each region separately and all launch at the same time.  I'm not sure this is significantly better than just letting the branch divergence take place, which if I'm not mistaken, would cause the four calculation types to be run in serial.

To deal with the for loop, you'll notice that there's a commented out arrSum3 function, which I wrote based off my previously (and probably poorly) written parallel reduction kernel.   Using it in place of the for loop drastically increased my runtime.  I feel like there's a clever way to accomplish what I'm trying to do with the for loop, but I'm just not that smart and my advisor is tired of me "wasting time" thinking about it.

Appreciate any help.

**EDIT**

Full code is located here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/21170233/1218689

Comment: What is conc? An array of doubles? Does that array change often? If it does, how frequent? Does any element of conc change during knowles_flux calculation, ie does the update happen in parallel?

Comment: You seem to be doing a lot of redundant summation of your conc array. If you do the prefix sum of the array once you can find the sum of any contiguous sub-region of the array from prefix_sum[high] - prefix_sum[low]. With very large arrays or very widely varying values in the array you might run into precision issues but it may work fine for your case.

Comment: @Xephon Conc is indeed an array of doubles.  Conc is run through the kernel, which calculates fluxes.  Fluxes is then used to advance conc through a time step.  No, conc does not change during the flux calculation.  conc is the array of concentrations for that time step and remains the same through five iterations of the knowles_flux calculation (5-6 times for a Runge Kutta integrator).

Comment: @mattnewport Thank you for bringing that to my attention.  Months ago I thought there might be some tricky way to initially compute a sum or array of sums that I could use to quickly compute these partial sums.  Now if I can bring the parallelism of the GPU to bear in quickly doing the prefix sum array, then maybe I might be in business.

Comment: You might want to take a look at NVIDIA's Thrust library - it has pre-written algorithms for doing prefix sums amongst other things.

Comment: @mattnewport I don't think Thrust will work for me.  It is purely host-side, right?  This algorithm would have to be callable from a kernel that is running the integrator on the GPU.

Comment: You call Thrust from the host side yes but you could use it to precompute your prefix sums once before launching your kernel. Essentially you're replacing your constant conc array with the prefix sum of that array.

Comment: See, this integration, for which the fluxes need to be calculated takes place entirely on the GPU. I did this to avoid the cost of host to GPU memory transfer.  I need a way to do this purely device side since each time step changes the conc array .

Comment: @mattnewport Because of the nature of the conc array, it changes every "iteration", you'll have to "pre-calculate" the sum arrray every cycle and transfer form host to device memory before flux calculation. Although I'm thinking a similar mechanism, I'd say keeping the data local in device mem is probably a better approach

Comment: @KarstenChu I don't see the manipulation and stepping forward of the conc array in your code. Do you mind share a little bit insight as how the array is changed? Based on that, if it has a pattern, there may be an algorithm you can work out to maintain a copy of the pre-calculated sum array in device memory and update according to changed conc array every cycle.

Comment: @Xephon Sure.  I didn't include it because it's a fairly hefty chunk of code.  I've posted it before and will link in an edit.

Comment: There was a similar situation in a fluid solver, the pressure solver had a kernel covering all cells. Dividing it into "vertical boundary"+"horizontal boundary"+"interior rectangle" kernels gave a boost for an extreme big map but gave an obstacle when map was small because more kernels mean more kernel overhead. Only way to hide that latency is overlapping concurrentible kernels. Run those 4 kernels at the same time, some of the lattency will be hidden and no harm should happen as long as they write to different addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming sgn() and abs() are not derived from "if"s and "else"s

```
__device__ double knowles_flux(int r, double *conc)
{
    double frag_term = 0;
    double flux = 0;

        //Calculation type : "Max"
        //no divergence
        //should prefer 20-30 extra cycles instead of a branching.
        //may not be good for CPU
        fluxA = (1-abs(sgn(r-(maxlength-1)))) * (-km*(r)*conc[r]+2*(ka)*conc[r-1]*conc[0]);
        //is zero if r and maxlength-1 are not equal

        //always compute this in shared memory so work will be equal for all cores, no divergence

        // you should divide kernel into several pieces to do a reduction
        // but if you dont want that, then you can try :
        for (int s = 0;s<someLimit ; s++) // all count for same number of cycles so no divergence
        {
            frag_term += conc[s] * (   abs(sgn( s-maxlength ))*sgn(1- sgn( s-maxlength ))  )* (      sgn(1+sgn(s-(r+1)))  );
        }
         //but you can make easier of this using "add and assign" operation
         // in local memory (was it __shared in CUDA?)
         //  global conc[] to local concL[] memory(using all cores)(100 cycles)
         // for(others from zero to upper_limit)
         // if(localID==0)
         // {
         //    frag_termL[0]+=concL[s]             // local to local (10 cycles/assign.)
         //    frag_termL[0+others]=frag_termL[0]; // local to local (10 cycles/assign.)
         // }  -----> uses nearly same number of cycles but uses much less energy
         //using single core (2000 instr. with single core vs 1000 instr. with 2k cores)
         // in local memory, then copy it to private registers accordingly using all cores



        //Calculation type : "F"

        fluxB = (  abs(sgn(r-(nc-1)))*sgn(1+sgn(r-(nc-1)))   )*(-(km)*(r)*conc[r] + 2*(km)*frag_term - 2*(ka)*conc[r]*conc[0] + 2*(ka)*conc[r-1]*conc[0]);
        // is zero if r is not greater than (nc-1)



        //Calculation type : "N"


        fluxC = (   1-abs(sgn(r-(nc-1)))   )*((kn)*pow(conc[0],(nc)) + 2*(km)*frag_term - 2*(ka)*conc[r]*conc[0]);
        //zero if r and nc-1 are not equal



    flux=fluxA+fluxB+fluxC; //only one of these can be different than zero

    flux=flux*(   -sgn(r-(nc-1))*sgn(1-sgn(r-(nc-1)))  )
    //zero if r > (nc-1)

    return flux;
}
```

Okay, let me open a bit:

```
if(a>b) x+=y;
```

can be taken as

```
if a-b is negative sgn(a-b) is -1
then adding 1 to that -1 gives zero ==> satisfies lower part of comparison(a<b)
x+= (sgn(a-b) +1) = 0 if a<b (not a>b), x unchanged

if(a-b) is zero, sgn(a-b) is zero
then we should multiply the upper solution with sgn(a-b) too!
x+= y*(sgn(a-b) +1)*sgn(a-b)
means
x+= y*( 0  +  1) * 0 = 0           a==b is satisfied too!

lets check what happens if a>b
x+= y*(sgn(a-b) +1)*sgn(a-b)
x+= y*(1 +1)*1  ==> y*2 is not acceptable, needs another sgn on outherside

x+= y* sgn((sgn(a-b)+1)*sgn(a-b))

x+= y* sgn((1+1)*1)

x+= y* sgn(2)   

x+= y only when a is greater than b
```

when there are too many

```
abs(sgn(r-(nc-1))
```

then you can re-use it as

```
tmp=abs(sgn(r-(nc-1))

.....  *tmp*(tmp-1) ....
...... +tmp*zxc[s] .....
......  ......
```

to decrease total cycles even more! Register accessing can be in the level of terabytes/s so shouldnt be a problem. Just as doing that for global access:

```
tmpGlobal= conc[r];

...... tmpGlobal * tmp .....
.... tmpGlobal +x -y ....
```

all private registers doing stuff in terabytes per second.

Warning: **reading** from conc[-1] shouldnt cause any faults as long as it is multiplied by zero if the real address of conc[0] is not real zero already . But **writing** is hazardous.

if you need to escape from conc[-1] anyway, you can multiply the index with some absolut-ified value too! See:

```
 tmp=conc[i-1] becomes   tmp=conc[abs((i-1))] will always read from positive index, the value will be multiplied by zero later anyway. This was lower bound protection.
  You can apply a higher bound protection too. Just this adds even more cycles.
```

Think about using vector-shuffle operations if working on a pure scalar values is not fast enough when accessing conc[r-1] and conc[r+1]. Shuffle operation between a vector's elements is faster than copying it through local mem to another core/thread.

Comment: "Warning: reading from conc[-1] shouldnt cause any faults as long as it is multiplied by zero if the real address of conc[0] is not real zero already . But writing is hazardous." Be careful when doing this since conc[-1] can contain NaN or Inf which, when multiplied by 0, might not be behave as expected...

Comment: @Dirk: good spot. Then using an index limiter as I mentioned in the end can protect it, can it? conc[abs(i-1)] for example. There must be a compiler option like -noNAN -noINF

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik This is quite neat, if the given conditions are met. On the other hand, it is terrible for ppl to maintain. If the code is bound for production, I would suggest not to use it. The next paranoia coder may well justify this code being potential source of other issue thus re-write the whole thing.

Comment: @Xephon okay, if this is not suitable, breaking all if's into separate kernels would be perfect just as Karsten has written in his question. Only issue would be kernel overhead which is only several hundred microseconds to half a millisecond and noticable for only smallest work loads. Yes, answer looks evil :P I hope this is not premature optimization. Also implementing sgn() and abs() can have function overhead thus consuming more private registers and locals decreasing performance.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik not to mention such sgn() and abs() are not that straight forward to define. If you want to create, assembly level maybe, functions that does not involve jump... Well, you get the picture.

Comment: @Xephon Cuda lets the assembly level fiddling I read from tutorials. But yeah, dividing boundary conditions to separate kernels would make it much clear and future proof. Karsten already answered his own question. Only %100 finished and never-to-be-touched code should be played with like that. Maybe bitfiddling with sign bit and some rightshifting(or left) can give sgn() maybe. But that would be another question :D